# Дополнение множества до универсума

Tags: алгоритм

Здравствуйте , стоит задача реализовать дополнения множества до универсума. Насколько я понимаю , универсум это множество которое включает в себя все элементы определенного типа , то есть универсум чисел это бесконечность , а дополнение до универсума , в результате получается множество которое включает все элементы данного типа , кроме тех что включает подмножество . Если я правильно сказал , то как это реализовать программно ?

Comment: Подумайте о множестве, как о булевой функции от числового параметра.

Answer (score 1):

```
bool IsInSet(int i)
{ 
  return i > -10 && i < 100 && i % 3 == 0;
}

void main()
{
  printf("Все числа из дополнения до универсума: ");

  int i = INT_MIN;

  do {
    if (!IsInSet(i))
      printf("%d ", i);

    if (i == INT_MAX)
      break;
    else 
      i++;
  } while (true);
}
```

Вот. Основной смысл программы укладывается в символ "!"